# How do I specify different getter and setter accessors for a Description in Magritte?

Tags: pharo

By convention you specify only the accessor: and Magritte uses the same name for both. Some comments in the code and in the http://book.seaside.st say that it supports having getters and setters with different names. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `MAPluggableAccessor`, something like this:

```
descriptionMonths
    <magritteDescription>

    ^ MANumberDescription new 
        priority: 30;
        label: 'Months';
        accessor: (MAPluggableAccessor 
            read: [ :this | this periodMonths ]
            write: [ :this :monthsNumber | this periodMonths: monthsNumber ]);
        yourself
```